# Editor Table with variable Dropdown

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, datatable, dropdown

Hello I have an editor table and would like to design one column as a variable dropdown. The values ​​for the dropdown come from the ControllerDrpDwn method implemented in the controller. How can i get this output as dropdown options?

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: { url: "/Controller/EditorTable"  , type: "POST"},
        table: "#tbl",
 
        fields: [{
            label: "abc:",
            name: "abc"
        },{
                label: "xyz:",
                name: "xyz",
                type: "select"
        //        option: Output from ControllerDrpDwn method
       
        }]
    });
```

This is the method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ControllerDrpDwn()
{ 
    return Ok(await _context.Dropdownoptions.Where(x => x.Selectbezeichnung == "xyz").Select(x => new
    { 
        name = x.Optionbezeichnung
    }).ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Based on the docs: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html and https://editor.datatables.net/reference/api/field().update(), which seems enable us to dynamically update options for field. And this is a similar question: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/137978/#Comment_137978

Answer (score 1):

If you write javascript codes in a Razor page, you can follow this code to get the result:

```
@{var options = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);}

editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: { url: "/Controller/EditorTable"  , type: "POST"},
        table: "#tbl",
 
        fields: [{
            label: "abc:",
            name: "abc"
        },{
                label: "xyz:",
                name: "xyz",
                type: "select"
                option: @Html.Raw(options)
       
        }]
});
```

But in controller, you need to change the code like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ControllerDrpDwn()
{ 
    return Ok(await _context.Dropdownoptions.Where(x => x.Selectbezeichnung == "xyz").Select(x => new
    { 
        label= x.Optionbezeichnung,
        value='value of item comes here'
    }).ToListAsync());
}
```